# On matrix norms 

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, terminology, norms

It is standard to define an induced matrix norm $|||\cdot|||$ from a vector norm $||\cdot||$ in this way:

$|||A|||=\max_{x \neq 0}{\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}}$.

Suppose we define a different function of matrices this way:

$f(A)=\inf_{x \neq 0}{\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}}$.

Has $f(\cdot)$ been studied  before? Does it have a standard name?

Answer (score 7):

By the [Courant-Fischer min-max theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_Theorem), if $A$ is Hermitian, then $f(A) = \lambda_n(A)$, the smallest eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Right! Of course, I managed to utterly confuse myself here.

Answer (score 6):

$|||A|||$ is the largest s-number (modulus of gen. eigenvalue).
$f(A)$ is the smallest s-number. It is 0 if $A$ is not injective.

Comment: S-numbers are also known as [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value).

Comment: This holds if the underlying norm is the Euclidean norm. With other norms, I have no idea if this has ever been studied.

Comment: @ Federico: They have been treated for operators on Banach spaces. See papers and books by Albrecht Pietsch, e.g.

Comment: @PeterMichor: Can you give a specific reference, please? Thanks!

Comment: s-numbers are just the non-hermitian equivalents of eigenvalues. just like eigenvalues, they can be defined for any possible hilbert space - and even on a banach space, as peter michor stresses.

Comment: @ Felix Goldberg:
MR0519680 (81a:47002) Reviewed 
Pietsch, Albrecht
Operator ideals. 
Mathematische Monographien [Mathematical Monographs], 16. VEB Deutscher Verlag der Wissenschaften, Berlin, 1978. 451 pp. 

Newer:
MR1863699 (2003h:47137)
